# What to do when Google change packages' url?

Tags: go

When I tried to upgrade third party packages, things went wrong. It seems Google has changed the url of those packages. What should I do now?

```
$ go get -u all                                                               
package google.golang.org/cloud: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud expects import "cloud.google.com/go"
package google.golang.org/cloud/bigquery: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/bigquery expects import "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
package google.golang.org/cloud/bigtable: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/bigtable expects import "cloud.google.com/go/bigtable"
package google.golang.org/cloud/bigtable/bttest: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/bigtable/bttest expects import "cloud.google.com/go/bigtable/bttest"
package google.golang.org/cloud/compute/metadata: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/compute/metadata expects import "cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata"
package google.golang.org/cloud/container: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/container expects import "cloud.google.com/go/container"
package google.golang.org/cloud/datastore: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/datastore expects import "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
package google.golang.org/cloud/errorreporting/apiv1beta1: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/errorreporting/apiv1beta1 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/errorreporting/apiv1beta1"
package google.golang.org/cloud/errors: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/errors expects import "cloud.google.com/go/errors"
package google.golang.org/cloud/language/apiv1beta1: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/language/apiv1beta1 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/language/apiv1beta1"
package google.golang.org/cloud/logging: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/logging expects import "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
package google.golang.org/cloud/logging/apiv2: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/logging/apiv2 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2"
package google.golang.org/cloud/logging/logadmin: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/logging/logadmin expects import "cloud.google.com/go/logging/logadmin"
package google.golang.org/cloud/monitoring/apiv3: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/monitoring/apiv3 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/monitoring/apiv3"
package google.golang.org/cloud/preview/logging: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/preview/logging expects import "cloud.google.com/go/preview/logging"
package google.golang.org/cloud/preview/logging/logadmin: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/preview/logging/logadmin expects import "cloud.google.com/go/preview/logging/logadmin"
package google.golang.org/cloud/pubsub: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/pubsub expects import "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
package google.golang.org/cloud/pubsub/apiv1: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/pubsub/apiv1 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub/apiv1"
package google.golang.org/cloud/speech/apiv1beta1: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/speech/apiv1beta1 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv1beta1"
package google.golang.org/cloud/storage: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/storage expects import "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
package google.golang.org/cloud/trace: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/trace expects import "cloud.google.com/go/trace"
package google.golang.org/cloud/vision: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/vision expects import "cloud.google.com/go/vision"
package google.golang.org/cloud/vision/apiv1: code in directory /Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/vision/apiv1 expects import "cloud.google.com/go/vision/apiv1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If any code of yours is using the google cloud API packages directly, update them to the new URL. If any of your dependent packages use the cloud API packages, make sure they get updated.
2. Delete the `/Users/laike9m/Dev/Go/src/google.golang.org/cloud` directory so that `go get -u all` stops trying to update the stuff under it and making noise.

Once whatever was bringing in the cloud packages is updated, it will download them under the new `cloud.google.com` path and everything will be fine.